# C++: Initialize array of objects with parameters within another class

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, member-initialization

I'm trying to create a class that will have array of objects of another class as its member. This "lower" class constructor demands a parameter (no default c-tor), and I'm not sure how to do this.

```
In .hpp
class ProcessingElement : public sc_core::sc_module
{
public:
    ProcessingElement( sc_core::sc_module_name name );
    sc_core::sc_module_name name;
};

In .cpp
ProcessingElement::ProcessingElement( sc_core::sc_module_name name ) : name(name) {
    //not relevant
}
```

And "upper" class:

```
In .hpp
class QuadPE : public sc_core::sc_module
{
public:
    QuadPE( sc_core::sc_module_name name );
    ProcessingElement pe[4];
};

In .cpp
QuadPE::QuadPE( sc_core::sc_module_name name ) : pe[0]("PE0"), pe[1]("PE1"), pe[2]("PE2"), pe[3]("PE3") {
    //non relevant
}
```

This obviously produces error, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I would like to avoid using vectors, if possible, so some solutions I found on SO that include vectors are not perfect for me.

As a note, `sc_core::sc_module_name` is a typedef of `const char*` or something similar, sadly can't look it up right now.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [aggregate initialize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) the array:

```
QuadPE::QuadPE( sc_core::sc_module_name name ) : pe{"PE0", "PE1", "PE2", "PE3"} {}
```

While you may not want to use `std::vector`, I still suggest you give [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) a look. It's an aggregate too, that serves as a thin (zero overhead) wrapper over a c-style array. Nevertheless, it has full value semantics and is a full-featured standard library container. So you may find it less clunky to work with.

Comment: Very obvious and yet still I couldn't think of it. Thank you.